# Elasticsearch - Limit docs count used for sum aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, sum, limit

I know it's not supposed to work that way, but is there a way to force sum aggregations to limit the sum based on the size set in the query?

Like in this query:

```
{
    "size" : 10,
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "query":{
                "match_all":{}
            },
            "filter": {
                // some filter     
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "value" : {
            "sum" :{
                "field":"value"
            }
         }
    }
}
```

If I have 100 docs, I'd like to retrieve only 10 docs and the sum of these  10 docs.

In a nutshell: I need a SELECT SUM(value) FROM table LIMIT 10, regardless the score.

Do you guys know if I can do it with ES?

Answer (score 0):

The [limit filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-limit-filter.html) seems to do what you want. Here is a simple example.

I set up a simple index and gave it some docs:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   }
}

POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"name":"a a", "val": 1}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"name":"a b", "val": 2}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"name":"a c", "val": 3}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"name":"b a", "val": 4}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"name":"b b", "val": 5}
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{"name":"b c", "val": 6}
```

Then I can get sum of the `"val"` field of the first two documents with `"name"` containing the term `"a"`, as follows:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "term": {
               "name": {
                  "value": "b"
               }
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "limit": {
               "value": 2
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "val_sum": {
         "sum": {
            "field": "val"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.73895097,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.73895097,
            "_source": {
               "name": "a b",
               "val": 2
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.73895097,
            "_source": {
               "name": "b a",
               "val": 4
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "val_sum": {
         "value": 6,
         "value_as_string": "6.0"
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/6be3fc75db339fa3810521dbcb61429cd885d1bf

Comment: Thank you, Sloan. The limit filter is really a good approach, but as the limit is applied _per_ _shard_, it still doesn't limit the docs the way I wanted. Bummer. Do you know if there is a way to limit the docs returned per index?

Comment: Ooh, right, I missed that. I can't think of anything off-hand, sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway, Sloan. For know, the only solutions I could come up was either set a single shard or (horrible, I know) "limit" / "shards_number". I'll use neither, though.